# ways to depict mathematical function charts in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I want to depict mathematical function charts (sine , log , exp,...) in wpf , I know only two way for it:

1- using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart:

```
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        var series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
        {
            Name = "Series1",
            Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
            IsVisibleInLegend = false,
            IsXValueIndexed = true,
            ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        };

        this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);

        for (int i=0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            series1.Points.AddXY(i, f(i));
        }
        chart1.Invalidate();
```

2- using xaml code :

```
<Canvas  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="PCanvas" VerticalAlignment="Center"     Margin="26,23,327,418">
              <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                 <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=SignalScaleSlider, Path=Value}" />
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Path Data="M 10,370 L 10,10 M 42,370 L 42,10 M 74,370 L 74,10 M 106,370 L 106,10 M 138,370 L 138,10 M 170,370 L 170,10
                  M 202,370 L 202,10 M 234,370 L 234,10 M 266,370 L 266,10 M 298,370 L 298,10

 ...
```

which one is better??

is there any other solution?
tnx.

Comment: and what is the special use of each?

Answer (score 1):

Charts are better and more flexible solution for your needs.

Comment: must I use them with system.form to use it in wpf? or it can be used directly? (I cannot add chart to a grid's children directly).

Comment: @abdolah you can use WPF toolkit charts:  http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535